# Set max length limit for string Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to send large string by route from client side to server side by HttpGet in this way:

```
//Client Side
string largeString="ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd...";
//suppose the length of the string is 3000
var returnedString=await HttpGet.GetFromJsonAsync("ReturnTheString/"+largeString);

//Server Side
[HttpGet]
[Route("ReturnTheString/{largeString}")]
public string ReturnString(string largeString)
{
int length = largeString.Length;
//here the length will be 254 not 3000
return largeString;
}
```

I tried to set the max length limit using the following links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#iis-options

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/#configuration

but nothing worked with me.

How can I solve this issue, please?

Comment: @HenkHolterman it will cause error

Comment: [FromBody] worked with HttPost or HttpPut when tried to use it with HttpGet gave me error

Comment: Have you tried the following route : `ReturnTheString/{largeString:length(0, 3000)}`?

Comment: Route contstraints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints

Comment: @Marius still get just 254. Thank you

Comment: Why are you using a GET method? You can use a POST, add an object with parameters with a max length using `MaxLength` attrubute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.maxlengthattribute?view=net-5.0 Also, having this big of a URL length isn't the best idea IMO.

Comment: @Marius I need to send string and create file and return it's bytes. I created static string in the controller and save the value in this static string and then in get I return what I want. but what if two clients click the button at the same time wouldn't be a problem cuz of the static string? that's why I'm trying in get directly